# Any way to restrict export within a package in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

Is there a way or pattern in NodeJS to share functions within the modules of a package only and not allow them to be shared from another package?

E.g if Package A has file1.js, file2.js and index.js. index.js uses functions from file1 and file2.

Package B uses Package A. It seems like all modules exported from file1 and file2 are also available to Package B. Can it be restricted to those exported from index.js of Package A only?

In short, is there a support for something like a protected scope?

Comment: export only what is required from the `index.js` of `PackageA`.

Answer (score 0):

as AZ_ said: only export that what you want to export.

example:

```
// file1
export const foo = () => { console.log("foo"); }
```

```
// file2
import {foo} from "./file1"

export const bar = () => { 
   foo();
   console.log("bar"); 
}
```

```
// index
import {bar} from "./bar"

// the package will only export bar
export { bar }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way, but I wrote an ESLint plugin specifically for this purpose: [eslint-plugin-export-scope](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-export-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can [choose which modules to export to the external code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78251561/8138591). Additionally, u can *clearly* communicate the **intention** that a code exported from a file should only be used inside a package and not outside of it (**package scoped**).

My solution is based on the idea from another programming language. According to the [convention](https://dart.dev/language) adopted by the Dart programming language created by Google:

> Unlike Java, Dart doesn't have the keywords public, protected, and private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it's private to its library.

So for a file that *only* exports **package-private code**, its name should be prefixed with an underscore `_`, for example `_packagePrivate.js`. *All* the **named exports** from this file (e.g., constants, functions) should also be prefixed with an underscore `_` too.

**JSDoc** has a special block tag [`@package`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-package):

> This symbol is meant to be **package-private**. Typically, this tag indicates that a symbol is available only to code in the same directory as the source file for this symbol.

The `@package` tag in JSDoc is the same as `@access package` (see [`@access`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-access)).

**TSDoc** provides a modifier tag [`@internal`](https://tsdoc.org/pages/tags/internal/):

> Designates that an API item is not planned to be used by third-party developers. The tooling may trim the declaration from a public release. In some implementations, certain designated packages may be allowed to consume **internal API items**, e.g. because the packages are components of the same product.

So as a result, the `_packagePrivate.ts` file might look like this:

```js
/**
 * @package
 * @internal
 */
export function _returnAPIKey(): string {
  return '...';
}

/**
 * @package
 * @internal
 */
export default _returnAPIKey();
```

According to the [JSDoc example for ES 2015 Modules](https://jsdoc.app/howto-es2015-modules)

> In most cases, you can simply add a JSDoc comment to the export statement that defines the exported value. If you are exporting a value under another name, you can document the exported value within its export block.