# Only expose certain exports to files outside folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module

Say we have a folder in which we have a lot of files that each export something:

**facade/A.tsx**

```
export const _A = () => {...}; // this export should NOT be visible for files outside `facade/`
```

**facade/B.tsx**

```
export const B = () => {...}; // this export should be visible for files outside `facade/`
```

**facade/C.tsx**

```
export const _C = () => {...}; // this export should NOT be visible for files outside `facade/`
```

What do I mean by "*this export should not be visible for files outside `facade/`*"? I mean:

**name.tsx**  (note: this file is not in the `facade/` folder)

```
import {A} from "./facade/A.tsx"; // Should not work
import {B} from "./facade/B.tsx"; // Should work
import {C} from "./facade/C.tsx"; // Should not work
```

---

Essentially, I guess I want a module ... I just don't want to have all the setup boilerplate files  as it seems overkill for a small folder.

So my question is, (without making modules -- because that's overkill) is it possible to restrain certain exports to export only to files in the same dir or subdir?

Answer (score 4):

No it's not possible.
What is usually done is creating an index.ts which export all "public" functions from said module. The nested ones still will be accessible, but it's more clear that they shouldn't be used.

```
// index ts

export * from "./facade/B.tsx"
```

Answer (score 3):

Creating a module for this purpose is inevitable and not a strenuous task at all. All u need is a `package.json` with an `exports` field to limit which submodules can be loaded from within the package. From the [official Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports):

> The "exports" field allows defining the entry points of a package when imported by name loaded via a node_modules lookup. It is an alternative to the "main" that can support defining subpath exports and conditional exports while encapsulating internal unexported modules

⚠️ Note that all paths defined in the `"exports"` must be relative file URLs starting with `./` except for the default one `.` (as mentioned in the official doc).

So in your case, the `package.json` inside your `facade` folder would be:

```json
{
    "name": "@facade",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "exports": {
        "./B.tsx": "./B.tsx"
    }
}
```

Now the external code outside of the `facade` folder (a.k.a the `@facade` package) can only `import {B} from "@facade/B.tsx";`. Both `@facade/A.tsx` and `"@facade/C.tsx"` are completely inaccessible to the external code.

[Another example from AWS](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/blob/d0b13796ad5490a4381009b32c76c8c65e7e0c16/packages/react/package.json#L16)

See [my bonus tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78251743/8138591) for additional ways to clearly communicate this intention.